# Robot FrameWork Collections - List comparison Issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, collections, robotframework

I am trying to compare two identical lists in Robot Framework . The code I am using is :

```
List Test
    Lists Should Be Equal    @{List_Of_States_USA}    @{List_Of_States_USA-Temp}
```

and the lists are identical with the following values :

```
@{List_Of_States_USA}    Alabama    Alaska    American Samoa    Arizona    Arkansas    California    Colorado
...               Connecticut    Delaware    District of Columbia    Florida    Georgia    Guam    Hawaii
...               Idaho    Illinois    Indiana    Iowa    Kansas    Kentucky    Louisiana
...               Maine    Maryland    Massachusetts    Michigan    Minnesota    Mississippi    Missouri
...               Montana    National    Nebraska    Nevada    New Hampshire    New Jersey    New Mexico
...               New York    North Carolina    North Dakota    Northern Mariana Islands    Ohio    Oklahoma    Oregon
...               Pennsylvania    Puerto Rico    Rhode Island    South Carolina    South Dakota    Tennessee    Texas
...               Utah    Vermont    Virgin Islands    Virginia    Washington    West Virginia    Wisconsin
...               Wyoming
```

This test fails with the following error:

```
FAIL    Keyword 'Collections.Lists Should Be Equal' expected 2 to 5 arguments, got 114.
```

I have searched SO and other sites for a solution, but could not figure out why this happened. Thanks in advance for support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a `$` not `@`. When you use `@`, robot expands the lists into multiple arguments.

From the [robot framework user's guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variables):

> When a variable is used as a scalar like ${EXAMPLE}, its value will be used as-is. If a variable value is a list or list-like, it is also possible to use as a list variable like @{EXAMPLE}. **In this case individual list items are passed in as arguments separately**.

Consider the case of `@{foo}` being a list with the values "one", "two" and "three". In such as case the following two are identical:

```
some keyword  @{foo}
some keyword  one  two  three
```

You need to change your statement to this:

```
Lists Should Be Equal    ${List_Of_States_USA}    ${List_Of_States_USA-Temp}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, As suggested by Bryan-Oakley above, I modified the test as follows:

```
${L1}   Create List @{List_Of_States_USA}
${L2}   Create List @{List_Of_States_USA-Temp}
Lists Should Be Equal   ${L1}   ${L2}
```

Now the test passed. Thanks Again @ Brian